# How to get data from app PowerBI as external user

Tags: web-scraping, powerbi

I am interested in downloading data from a national public dataset referring to Vaccine in Italy.

https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzg4YmI5NDQtZDM5ZC00ZTIyLTgxN2MtOTBkMWM4MTUyYTg0IiwidCI6ImFmZDBhNzVjLTg2NzEtNGNjZS05MDYxLTJjYTBkOTJlNDIyZiIsImMiOjh9

In particular I am interested in downloading the last table.
I tried to use a scraping model via HTML, but it seems that data is not stored directly into the HTML source page.

Then I thought to use the code below in Python 3.9:

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import pyautogui
import win32api
import win32gui
from win32con import *

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
LINK = ".tableEx .bodyCells div:nth-child(1) > .pivotTableCellWrap:nth-child("
TO_ADD ="1)"
data = []
action = ActionChains(driver)
  
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzg4YmI5NDQtZDM5ZC00ZTIyLTgxN2MtOTBkMWM4MTUyYTg0IiwidCI6ImFmZDBhNzVjLTg2NzEtNGNjZS05MDYxLTJjYTBkOTJlNDIyZiIsImMiOjh9")
driver.set_window_size(784, 835)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
for i in range(1,293):

    print(i)
    if i%10==0:
        win32api.SetCursorPos((1625,724))
        win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, x, y, -3, 0)

        time.sleep(6)
    else:
        pass
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    TO_ADD = str(i)+")"
    action.move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, LINK+TO_ADD)).perform()
    action.context_click().send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'C:\Users\migli\Documents\Learning\copy.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,0.1)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'C:\Users\migli\Documents\Learning\copiaselez.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,0.1)
    pyautogui.click()
    data.append(pyperclip.paste())
```

Images for clicking:

**copiaselez**

[image]

**copy**

[image]

This seems to achieve what I am trying to do. But then it blocks around the 14th cycle. I don't know why. Maybe I should scroll down the page in some manner, but I tried to do it manually during the code inserting an sleep time around 10th cycle, but it gets error as well.

I also thought using an API but it seems not to exist one.
Any idea is accepted.

Comment: This is a report, published publicly using [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) and if you take a look at the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web#limitations), you will see that exporting data is not allowed in this case. So the best way to get this data is to ask the publisher for it.

Comment: Well thanks, but it is not easy contacting the publisher. I was more interested in a web scraping solution instead able to get the data. In fact, copying is not forbidden but it is very uneasy to do it since you cannot select all the data but one by one. So exporting actually is allowed bit it would take a lot of time